# How to copy 1 slide of a PowerPoint, paste it to a specific location of another PowerPoint, then create a new Powerpoint from it using python-pptx?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm able to copy the second slide of a test.pptx to a copy.pptx, and create a new copy2.pptx. But the new PPT is corrupted.

Here is my code:

```
import collections
import collections.abc

import copy
from pptx import Presentation


def copy_slide(prs, source, target_index):

    dest = prs.slides.add_slide(source.slide_layout)
    for shp in dest.shapes:
        shp.element.getparent().remove(shp.element)
    # Copy shapes from source, in order
    for shape in source.shapes:
        new_shape = copy.deepcopy(shape.element)
        dest.shapes._spTree.insert_element_before(new_shape, 'p:extLst')
    # Copy rels from source
    for key, val in source.part.rels.items():
        target = val._target
        dest.part.rels.add_relationship(val.reltype, target, val.rId, val.is_external)
    # Move appended slide into target_index
    prs.slides.element.insert(target_index, prs.slides.element[-1])
    return dest

prs = Presentation('test.pptx')
source = prs.slides[1]

prs2 = Presentation('copy.pptx')

copyslide = copy_slide(prs2, source, 1)

prs2.save('copy2.pptx')

print(copyslide)
```

I'm getting following error in the terminal:

```
UserWarning: Duplicate name: 'ppt/slideLayouts/_rels/slideLayout9.xml.rels'
  return self._open_to_write(zinfo, force_zip64=force_zip64)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @MadPhysicist hope you'll understand now. basically I'm trying to copy slide from one ppt to another ppt and generate new file of it to keep original files unmodified.

Comment: One slide or could you use a template presentation and hence copy the lot?

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. Is there an actual problem with the output?

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, new ppt file generated is corrupted and needs to repair every time I open it.

Comment: I presume - despite your "every time I open it" - saving the file in PowerPoint makes the nastygram go away. Probably not ideal but I want to understand whether PowerPoint has trouble after the first load.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar using the following code:

```
import sys
from pptx import Presentation
import copy

def merge_powerpoint_ppts(pres_loc1, pres_loc2, output_loc):
    pres1 = Presentation(pres_loc1)
    pres2 = Presentation(pres_loc2)  
    for slide in pres2.slides:
        sl = pres1.slides.add_slide(pres1.slide_layouts[2])
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            element = shape.element
            newelement = copy.deepcopy(element)
            sl.shapes._spTree.insert_element_before(newelement, 'p:extLst')
    pres1.save(output_loc + "\Output.ppt")
```

Comment: I tried with your code but its adding whole second ppt to end. I want to add specific slide at specific location and also at **" pres1.slides.add_slide(pres1.slide_layouts[2]) "** after creating new layout the default slide message( Click to add text) is getting overlapped with copied content.